# jQuery: selecting grandparents

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a better way to select grandparent elements in jQuery in order to avoid this ?

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().children(".title, .meta").fadeIn("fast");
```

Thanks.

Comment: and what about children().children().children().children(".title") ?

Comment: Couldn't resist, you can use $(this).gparent(2) with the code provided in my downvoted answer. Don't know why it's downvoted, since it's the solution that answers your question...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the `parents()` method which matches parents against a selector

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Or if you're using 1.4 there is a new `parentsUntil()` method

http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/

Answer (score 29):

In addition to `parents()`, as they've said, you should also [check out `closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). Read the comparison in the documentation there, but its main differences are that it searches for only one result, and it includes `$(this)` in what it searches (could get the thing you're searching from if you're not specific enough). Pros and cons.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote this simple plugin because I thought I had an unambiguous class selection somewhere giving me errors. Selecting grandparent seemed more direct than `$().parents()` for this particular case.

Well, I used this once then realized I actually had a spelling error. Not sure how helpful it really is. `$('myelem').gparent(2);` gets you the grandparent of 'myelem'.

```
(function( $ ){
$.fn.gparent = function( recursion ){
    if( recursion == undefined ) recursion = 2;
    if(typeof(recursion) == "number"){
        recursion = parseInt( recursion );
        if( recursion > 0 ){
            gparent_holder = $(this);
            for(var gparent_i = 0; gparent_i < recursion; gparent_i++){
                gparent_holder = gparent_holder.parent();
            }
            return gparent_holder;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    else return false;
}
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: I like this solution.  We're into jQuery >2.0 and there's still no straightforward, clean way to navigate 'k' levels up.  Seems like a trivial thing to add to the base framework.

Comment: nice to bring up recursiveness. A recursive function are a great solution for problems like these... yet your solution is not recursive. I posted a recursive snippet as an answer to this question

Answer (score 3):

Use the `parents()` selector to get all parents of an element. You can then either search the collection, or iterate over it if you want to affect all ancestors.

Answer (score 3):

@Femi had an answer to do this, and mentioned recursion, yet his solution was not recursive, here's a recursive jQuery solution for getting ancestors of an item:

```
$.fn.gparent = function( recursion ){
   console.log( 'recursion: ' + recursion );
   if( recursion > 1 ) return $(this).parent().gparent( recursion - 1 );
   return $(this).parent();
};
```

If this is your HTML:

```
<div id='grandparent'>
  <div id='parent'>
    <div id='child'>
      child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can call

```
console.log( $('#child').gparent( 2 ) );
```

to get the grandparent of element `child`. [Here's the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waee1016/)

Comment: why on earth does this get a downvote without a comment... it's recursive, it's documented, a Fiddle provided to show it works, and it's the answer to the OP's question... SO should make it impossible to downvote without an explanation. Now a perfectly working solution (which I use a lot!) is not showing as a valid one...

Comment: Instead of adding our own function to do `gparent(2)` we can use `parents().eq(2)`

Answer (score 1):

Using [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) and [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) get the same results.

Example instead of using this :

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().children(".title").fadeIn("fast");
```

you can use this :

```
$(this).parents().children(".title").fadeIn("fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic Example

```
<div id="europe">
   <div>
       <span id="denmark">Minimum Stok</span> 
   </div>
</div>

$('span#denmark').parents("div#europe").attr('class', 'place')
```

Result;

```
<div id="europe" class="place">
   <div>
       <span id="denmark">Minimum Stok</span> 
   </div>
</div>
```