# removing parent of a parent div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form that if user clicks remove, i need to remove the whole row.

```
            <div id='a_<?php echo $a;?>'>
                    <div class='leftDesc'>Code</div>
                    <div class='inputText'><input type='text' name='code[]' value='<?php echo $code;?>' id='code[]'></div>
                    <div class='centerDesc'>Description</div>
                    <div class='inputText'><input type='text' name='desc[]' value='<?php echo $desc;?>' size='32' maxlength='32' id='desc[]'></div>
                    <div class='centerDesc'><input type='button' class='remDisp' value='Remove Code' id='removeCode_<?php echo $a;?>'></div>
            </div>
```

when user clicks remove button, i want to remove the whole row (the div a_$a)

how do i write basically:

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

Comment: Post the entire handler for that button

Comment: lol. that works.  parent.parent seemed way to silly to write.  please forgive such a ridiculous question.....

Comment: if you know parent's id `$(this).parents('#parent id').remove();`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP answered his own question in his question.

Comment: @AlexandreDiacov if you know parent's id, then just remove it: `$('#parent_id').remove();`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369913/jquery-selecting-grandparents

Comment: well, i want to delete this to avoid the embarassment,  at least this is here for someone else to find :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for an alternative approach that isn't dependent on the element position, associate them by a data attribute or class, like this: [Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/ixAYASuH/1/edit)

```
<div id="bar"></div>
<button class="remDisp" data-foo="bar">Some Button</button>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var buttons = $('.remDisp'); //get a reference to your buttons
    buttons.click(function() { //add the click function to the buttons
      var foo = $(this).attr('data-foo'); //get "foo" attr (value of "bar" in this case)
      $('#'+foo).remove(); //find the element with id of foo's value (bar)
    });

  });
<script>
```

Do you mean "Where do I put my javascript code and how do I attach it to the button?"

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var buttons = $('.remDisp'); //get a reference to your buttons
    buttons.click(function() { //add the click function to the buttons
      $(this).parent().parent().remove(); //remove the grandparent of the clicked button.
    });

  });
<script>
```

Comment: i appreciate the response.  the answer was user silliness.  ill tick ya.