# Find the parents parent element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the HTML as follows. what i need is when someone clicks on the span element i want to find its parents parent element check some conditions. i used prev() method but it gives me only the near parent(*parent2 here*)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="contain">
        <div id="parent1">
            <div class="parent2">
                <span> Click here</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

var currentComponent = $(event.target).prev(); //*here i get parent2*

How can i find the parents parent element(in this case *parent2*). i am not very familiar with jquery so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read about .parents() and .parentsUntil(). In your case, what is the expected parent element?

Comment: Try this : $(event.target).parents('#parent1') or $(event.target).parent().parent()

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369913/jquery-selecting-grandparents

Comment: $(event.target).parent().parent() will give the result.

Comment: If elements are modifying their ancestors, descendants, or siblings, your app will turn into spaghetti real quick. read up on one day dataflow and idempotent view functions

Comment: use parents function

Answer (score 4):

You can try [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

From the docs:

> the .closest() method searches through these elements and their ancestors in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements. 
>   (...)
>    get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and .

It traverses up through the element ancestors in the DOM and **returns the first one** that matches the `selector` you passed as an argument. So, in your example, you can do something like that:

```
$("span").on("click", function(e) {
  var myParent = $(this).closest(".parent2");
  var parentOfMyParent = $(this).closest(".parent1");
  var contain = $(this).closest(".contain");
  var containerAbove = $(this).closest(".container");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
var currentComponent = $(event.target).parent().parent()
```

To do it in a single call, you can use

```
var currentComponent = $(event.target).closest(".parent1")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fiddle**:

https://jsfiddle.net/c624re4o/

**Code**:

```
var grandParent = $(this).parent().parent();
```

**Full Working Code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("span").click(function () {
    var grandParent = $(this).parent().parent();
    alert(grandParent.attr('id')); // Just for Testing
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("span").click(function () {
    var grandParent = $(this).parent().parent();
    alert(grandParent.attr('id')); // Just for Testing
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="contain">
        <div id="parent1">
            <div class="parent2">
                <span> Click here</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use .closest() or .parents() function with selector like .parents('#elementid')